# Primefaces datatable not saving data

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I'm new in Java and I trying to use primefaces datatable to save data in database. I can edit some value in datatable, but after refreshing nothing changed. Here is my code.

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {


    private int id;
    public String name = null;
    public String surname = null;
    public String username = null;
    public String description = null;
    public String email = null;
    public String phone = null;


@Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

public int getId(){
     return id;
}
public void setId(int id){
this.id = id;
}
@Column(name = "Name")
public String getName(){
return name;
}
public void setName(String Name){
this.name = Name;
}
@Column(name = "Surname")
public String getSurname(){     
return surname;
```

**LogonTest.java**

```
@ViewScoped
@SessionScoped
@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean(name = "logonTest")
public class LogonTest implements Serializable{
     @PersistenceUnit(unitName="Webbeans_RESOURCE_LOCAL")
     private EntityManagerFactory emf;
    public List<User> getUserList() {
        return userList;
    }

    public void setUserList(List<User> userList) {
        this.userList = userList;
    }

    public List<User> userList = new ArrayList();


    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
         EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
         // Read the existing entries and write to console
         Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u");
         userList = q.getResultList();
         System.out.println("Size: " + userList.size());
    }

    public LogonTest() {

    }

}
```

**TableBean.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;  
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.List;  
import java.util.UUID;  





import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;  





import org.primefaces.event.RowEditEvent;  

@ViewScoped
@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean(name = "tableBean")

public class TableBean implements Serializable {  

    private List<User> carsSmall;  

    public TableBean() {  
        carsSmall = new ArrayList<User>();  

     populateRandomCars(carsSmall, 9);  
    }  

   private void populateRandomCars(List<User> list, int size) {  
      for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)  
          list.add(new User());  
   }  



public List<User> getCarsSmall() {  
        return carsSmall;  
    }  

    public void onEdit(RowEditEvent event) {  
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(" Edited", ((User) event.getObject()).getName());  

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
    }  

    public void onCancel(RowEditEvent event) {  
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(" Cancelled", ((User) event.getObject()).getName());  

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: how do you are put data in database?? maybe entities must be refreshed...

Comment: where are your xhtml???